# adding objects in a list, am i doing it right?

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how many footballs would you want?");

            int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<football> ballist = new List<football>();

            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("how much should football {0} weigh?", i+1);
                int weight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                ballist.Add(new football(weight));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("amount of footballs is {0}", amount);            
            ballist.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.GetWeight()));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    class football
    {
        private int weight = 0;

        public int GetWeight()
        {
            return weight;

        }

        public football(int weigh)
            {
            weight = weigh;
            }

    }
}
```

adding objects in a list, am i doing it right?

Comment: Looks right enough..  of course it depends a bit on what you want to do later, but yes, you will have a list of footballs with a weight.  You could simplify your your football object - but as a start you will get there.

Comment: There is a dedicated site for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (for question like "is my code ok?").  Here it's offtopic, unless your code doesn't works, but then it still lack details of what doesn't work, with what error, etc. Also, take a look at [naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx), class and method names should be capitalized, though I am myself not following it fully (e.g. I'd call field `weight` as `_weight` to avoid having problem which you solve by giving parameter name `weigh` without `t`).

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative is to let user input *all* the weights in *one go* and *generate* the list:

```
  Console.WriteLine("please, input footballs' weights separated by comma");

  String input = Console.ReadLine();

  List<football> ballist = input
    .Split(',')
    .Select(item => new football(int.Parse(item)))
    .ToList();
```

Some suggestions on `Football` class

```
  // We usually start classes with capital letter
  class Football {
    private int m_Weight;

    // C# is not Java, so use properties, which are more readable
    public int Weight {
      get {
        return m_Weight;
      }
      private set {
        // validate input
        if (value <= 0)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value"); 

        m_Weight = value;  
      }
    }

    // "weight" - let argument correspond to property
    public football(int weight) {
      Weight = weight;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The adding to the list is right. I would recomend you to use property for the Weight.

```
    class football
    {
        public int weight { get; set; }
    }
```

If you dont want to have any code on the get/set.

```
public int _weight;
public int weight
{
    get
    {
        //Your Code here
        return _weight;
     }
     set
     {
         //And Here
         _weight = value;
     }
}
```